# How to count unique users in a fixed time window in a Kafka stream app?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We have a kafka message in a sole topic for each event a user does on our platform. Each of the events / kafka messages has a common field userId. We now want to know from that topic how many unique users we had every hour. So we are not interested in the event types and the individual counts for an user. We just want to know how many unique users were active in every hour.
What is the easiest way to achieve this? My current idea seems not to be very simple, see the pseudo code here:

```
stream
 .selectKey() // userId
 .groupByKey() // group by userid, results in a KGroupedStream[UserId, Value]
 .aggregate( // initializer, merger und accumulator simply deliver a constant value, the message is now just a tick for that userId key
   TimeWindows.of(3600000)
 ) // result of aggregate is KTable[Windowed[UserId], Const]
 .toStream // convert in stream to be able to map key in next step
 .map() // map key only (Windowed[Userid]) to key = startMs of window to and value Userid
 .groupByKey() // grouping by startMs of windows, which was selected as key before
 .count() // results in a KTable from startMs of window to counts of users (== unique userIds)
```

Is there an easier way? I probably overlook something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two thing you can do:

1. Merge `selectKey()` and `groupByKey()` into `groupBy()`
2. You don't need the `toStream().map()` step, but you can do regrouping with a new key directly on the first `KTable`

Something like this:

```
stream.groupBy(/* put a KeyValueMapper that return the grouping key */)
      .aggregate(... TimeWindow.of(TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1))
      .groupBy(/* put a KeyValueMapper that return the new grouping key */)
      .count()
```

Comment: Second `groupBy` is creating `KeyValueStore<Windowed<K>,V>` to store counts for each specific window. Since `KeyValueStore` doesn't support TTL and the number of windows are always growing, how should we do cleanup for second state store?

Comment: The example in the answer does not use `windowedBy()` and thus the issue you point out does not exist. Atm, there is not way to cleanup the second store if your first aggregation is windowed. It's not really supported to aggregate a windowed-KTable atm -- it's a known gap.